# Construct template via javascript, insert into page

Tags: meteor, tabs, meteor-blaze

I have a "tabbed" application I'm developing.

I had used an array of objects stored in a `Session` variable to create these tabs and simply referenced it in the template. This renders what I'm looking for successfully and makes sense. The short version is:

```
<template name="tabs">
  {{#each tabs}}
    {{> Template.dynamic template=templateName data=getTemplateData}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

But it appears to re-render every tab each time I add/remove a tab from the array and re-set the `Session` variable. I have way too many documents potentially referenced in each tab to make re-rendering all of them regularly a viable solution.

**If I'm mistaken or was doing this wrong please let me know.**

My second thought is to manually add/remove individual tabs from a regular array and reflect this via good old event-driven methods on the page. I have the template name I wish to use for a given tab and the data that needs to be used in it is stored in a `Session` variable with a unique name.

This should keep the other tabs from re-rendering when I add/remove another tab, but each tab still be subscribed to its own data individually.

I'm stuck on how to create a template instance via javascript so that I can insert it via jQuery. Thoughts?

Comment: Blaze.render might be what I'm looking for... I always post questions after trying for an hour to figure it out just to figure it out myself 12 seconds later.

Answer (score 1):

`Blaze.renderWithData` was what I was looking for.